# cookie_secure=TRUE and problem in userdata

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies

why in codeigniter when that `$config['cookie_secure']` is `TRUE`, not work `$this->session->userdata()` and return is false?
what di i do?

application\config\config.php:

```
$config['cookie_secure']    = TRUE;
```

```
$newdata = array(
                'user'  => $this->input->post('useradmin'),
                'logged_in' => TRUE
                );
            $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);

////////////////////// in following code return is false if $config['cookie_secure'] = TRUE; //////////////////////////////////
function foreign_tourt(){
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
        $this->load->view('admin/foreign_tour');
        }else{
        return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: cookie secure is for http over ssl (https) only.

Answer (score 4):

As it is said in the config.php file itself:

```
//|' cookie_secure' =  Cookies will only be set if a secure HTTPS connection exists
```

If your website is not on HTTPS, cookies will not be sent. Set is as

```
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
```

in config.php and everything will work again